# Monitor a Spreadsheet Cell for a Change, Prompt User for Response and Put User Input into a Different Sheet but Same Cell Address

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a cell containing a drop-down list with two values 'A' and 'B' where 'A' is available and 'B' is booked. I'd like to create the situation where when the user changes the cell from 'A' to 'B', an input box pops up asking the user to enter their name, they then click ok and the name is stored in the same cell position on another sheet.

Edited code and this one works. I've learned 'Stacks'Thanks. Used 'B5' to test data transfer between the two sheets. How do I make sheet listen to all the cells and grab the cell range selected by user.?

```
var globalVariableForDropDown = "";

function onEdit(e) {
//Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();

Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);

if (cellEdited === "B5") {
//Run a input box
globalVariableForDropDown = e.value;
var theUserInput = Browser.inputBox('Enter name please');
};

//Place user input in corresponding cell on iNames sheet

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('iNames');    
var range = sheet.getRange('B5');
    range.setValue(theUserInput);

};
```

Comment: Google `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Looks like you've got `gsFunctionToRun` in two places.  You are referring to the same function inside of that function.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor a cell, and use an input box, the code would look like this:

### gs Code - Monitor Editing

```
var globalVariableForDropDown = "";

function onEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

  var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);

  if (cellEdited === "B3") {
    //Run a input box
    globalVariableForDropDown = e.value;
    var theUserInput = Browser.inputBox('Enter the Info');
    //Run a function to process the input
    gsFunctionToRun(theUserInput);
  };
}
```

For a Dialog Box, the code would look something like this:

### gs Code - Monitor Editing

```
var globalVariableForDropDown = "";

function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

  var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);

  if (cellEdited === "B3") {
    //Run a dialog box
    globalVariableForDropDown = e.value;
    displayUserDialog();
  };
}
```

You need to modify that code for your needs.  Change the cell notation of "B3" to the cell you want to monitor.

### gs Code - Show User Dialog

```
function displayUserDialog() {

  //Logger.log('displayUserDialog ran: ');

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DialogBox')
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(650)
    .setHeight(450)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'My Dialog Name');
};
```

### DialogBox.html - HTML file for Dialog Box

```
<div>

  <input id="idNameInput" type="text" value="Enter Something">

  <input type='button' value="Update Spreadsheet" onclick='fncCallServerToDoSomething()'>
</div>

<script>

  function fncCallServerToDoSomething() {
    console.log('fncCallServerToDoSomething ran!');

    var aReturnedValue = document.getElementById("idNameInput").value;

    console.log("value of input field: " + aReturnedValue);

    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .gsFunctionToRun(aReturnedValue);

    //google.script.host.close();
  };

  function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  };
</script>
```

### gs Code To Write Data

```
function gsFunctionToRun(argValueRetrieved) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheetToWriteValueTo = ss.getSheetByName('Your Sheet Name to Write to');
  var cellToWriteTo = theSheetToWriteValueTo.getRange(globalVariableForDropDown);
  cellToWriteTo.setValue(argValueRetrieved);
}
```

Add the sheet name that you want to write to.

Comment: thanks for coming back. Getting  Cannot read property "value" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code") in the gs Code - Monitor Editing part of the code

Comment: You are running the code from the code editor.  `e` is returned from the edit event.  Because there was no edit event, `e` is undefined.  This is one situation, where you'll need to test the code by actually editing a cell.

Comment: Thank you. On editing the cell the code works great. I've edited the code to use an inputBox, is there any advantage to this? How do I place the value of the inputBox in the second page 'iNames' in the corresponding edited filed on first page 'booking' i.e. 'B4' cell edited on 'booking' page input goes to 'B4' on 'iNames' page?

Comment: See update to my answer at the top of the answer.  Did you replace `Your Sheet Name to Write to` with 'iNames'?